# Liferay on weblogic doesn't invalidate portlet session

Tags: session, liferay, weblogic

I use Liferay 6.2 GA4 portal on WebLogic server 10.3.6.0 and I found out one annoying problem.

1. I log in as UserA.
2. Display portlet which stores data to portlet session.
3. I log out.
4. I log in as UserB.
5. Display the same portlet which stores data to portlet session.
6. Portlet **shows data of UserA instead of UserB**.

I added by ext-plugin some debug log messages to `com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletSessionListenerManager` and `com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletSessionTracker` and found out that session (sessionId) passed to the **PortletSessionTracker.add** method is different than one passed to **invalidate** method. See log messages below:

```
2016-01-28 10:38:34,191 [PortletSessionTracker:40] Adding session with id=4s6HmE3LdwWuUdOilk7-ytJLqJh1LnCiTKzoeH9YVSBM2USJuxU9
2016-01-28 10:40:38,875 [PortletSessionListenerManager:187] Destroying session with id=S4qHmPDaSTLkwkmEo6gDLt4W0U-siGlU_GNa1LJelXTtQvSaRyEd
2016-01-28 10:40:38,875 [PortletSessionTracker:73] Removing session with id=S4qHmPDaSTLkwkmEo6gDLt4W0U-siGlU_GNa1LJelXTtQvSaRyEd
```

**session.invalidate();** in `com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletSessionTracker#invalidate` is not called. 
There is not error in portlet because on Tomcat it works ok. And on Tomcat **session.invalidate();** is called.

**Weblogic.xml:**

```
<weblogic-web-app
        xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd"
        >
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <page-check-seconds>60</page-check-seconds>
    </jsp-descriptor>

    <session-descriptor>
        <debug-enabled>true</debug-enabled>
        <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
        <cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
    </session-descriptor>

    <container-descriptor>
        <filter-dispatched-requests-enabled>false</filter-dispatched-requests-enabled>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.antlr.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.mozilla.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.xmlpull.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
        <optimistic-serialization>true</optimistic-serialization>
        <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
    </container-descriptor>

    <context-root>/</context-root>

    <wl-dispatch-policy>ejbtp_liferay</wl-dispatch-policy>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem? Thanks for any idea or help.

Comment: Haven't use LR for a few years. It kept a session which, (through a cookie?), remains on the client. LR sessions are designed somewhat stateful. Session pipes may be being reused for up to half hour (there is a timeout setting in the server ). This combo is possibly what you are running in to. LR administrators swapping user through the menus don't have this problem. Look for 'keep session' timeouts in LR and Weblogic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had a tricky reason. Our customer wanted to have different name for session id cookie - not the default **jsessionid**. I set the modified jsessionid on liferay portal war but not on another wars like theme and portlet apps. These wars therefore used the default jsessionid whereas portal used the modified one. The default one was used by **add** method, the modified one by **invalidate** method.

So solution was to modify the session id cookie also in portlet and theme wars.